# Have trouble with Java and TensorFlow retrain model

Tags: java, tensorflow

I am new in DeepLearining, and I try to make friend Java and TensorFlow Inception model

I retrained model with retrain.py script, so this create .pb file and .txt with serialized model of my graph and labels for it. So, now I try to connect Java and new retrained model.

So, I changed original LabelImage.java with new nodes DecodeJpeg and , difference between them see in LabelImageOriginal.java and LabelImage.java.

So now I've an error:

> Output 0 of type float does not match declared output type string for
>   node     recv_DecodeJpeg/contents_0 = Recvclient_terminated=true,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=6706969514627308055,
>   tensor_name="DecodeJpeg/contents:0", tensor_type=DT_STRING,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"

And what can i do with that i dont know...

https://github.com/nbarskov/LabelImage - GIT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using training made with python API as input to LabelImage module in java API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628829/using-training-made-with-python-api-as-input-to-labelimage-module-in-java-api)