# Using tensor flow retrained graph with LabelImage example

Tags: java, python, tensorflow

I am trying to take the output graph produced by [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) in the tensorflow examples and run it back into the LabelImage.java to recognize images which I've used to retrain the original inception V3 mode.

A version of this question was asked in [Using training made with python API as input to LabelImage module in java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628829/using-training-made-with-python-api-as-input-to-labelimage-module-in-java-api)

As the original question and answer pointed out, the node names changed between the inception V5 model used for LabelImage and the output model produced by retrain.py.

The answer provided did resolve the node name confusion, but it introduced an additional problem.  The image classification no longer works.  I ran LearnImage against the inception V5 model giving it a picture of a strawberry, and it reported "strawberry".  When I run the strawberry picture into the retrained model (using the code changes suggested by the answer), it give me "tulips" name by way of answer.  In other words, the classification fails.

When I stitch the retrained input and output nodes into the original [LabelImage.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java)  on line 112

I get this error:

```
     [java] Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Output 0 of type float does not match declared output type string for node _recv_DecodeJpeg/contents_0 = _Recv[client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-538792158466408467, tensor_name="DecodeJpeg/contents:0", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()
```

It feels like the input/output between nodes in the inception V5 model do not match the input/outputs between nodes in the retrained V3 model.  I can't find any documentation on these models or their parameters or how they were trained: there's a comment in the LearnImage.java

```
      // Some constants specific to the pre-trained model at:
  // https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip
  //
  // - The model was trained with images scaled to 224x224 pixels.
  // - The colors, represented as R, G, B in 1-byte each were converted to
  //   float using (value - Mean)/Scale.
  final int H = 224;
  final int W = 224;
  final float mean = 117f;
  final float scale = 1f;
```

I suspect these are not appropriate for the retrained V3 model that comes out of Retrain.py

ideas?